# Did Bane really crush Batman's skull?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In The Dark Knight Rises, when Bane is beating up Batman and then punches him repeatedly in the head, we see that Batman's head flattens on the side. Does this imply that Bane has actually crushed Batman's skull?

Comment: Uh, that's his *mask*. (And no, Wayne does not appear to have a crushed head later on in prison.)

Comment: I am to assume that Batman's mask sits very tightly on his head and  bending it would also crush through his skull considering the significant dent depth and mask being made of some sort of metal?

Comment: Imagine a half helmet. It fits the contours of your skull, but when it's dented it actually *absorbs* the blow. That's pretty much his cowl, only with ears and a mask.

Comment: The point of a helmet is to cushion against impacts. A form-fitting helmet without any padding wouldn't be very effective at that. It would be like you had a car tire that would dent the rim when compressed. Riding over anything but a smooth road would be costly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Nolan's Batman](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batsuit_%28Nolan_Films%29) has a **thick graphite cowl** that acts as a *helmet*. It's not skin tight and actually protects his head. What you saw in that scene is Bane breaking that helmet. Bruce does sustain some head injuries, as seen in the clip below, but they seem like bruises and he does recuperate.